# Can an large acer survive being cut right back

Tags: maple

I have just been given an acer, the only problem being it was a very large acer in a pot, it has been cut right down to about 6 inches from the ground, the root are good, will it survive?

Comment: Please post some pictures. Before and afters would be great but afters may be enough.

Comment: There's only one way to find out. Don't let the root ball dry out (but it won't need much water while nothing is growing) and wait. If nothing happens in 12 months, give up!

Comment: What was the caliper (diameter) of the trunk where it was cut?

Comment: Do you know the variety of Acer,or at least whether it is a Japanese Acer?

Comment: As far I know, acers will not crate new trunks (which is a good characteristic on gardens). So it depends: are there branches and buds below where you would cut?